# comparing results from groupby query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I had a query which resulted in the table below.

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═════════════════════╤═════════╕
│"title"                                            │"count(theme)"       │"x.name" │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════╡
│"Game of thrones"                                  │8                    │"X1"     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────┤
│"Game of thrones"                                  │4                    │"X2"     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────┤
│"Game of empire"                                   │4                    │"X1"     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────┤
│"Game of empire"                                   │4                    │"X2"     │
```

However, I will like to return the result below because the count(theme) is not equal for the group.

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
│"title"                                            │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
│"Game of thrones"                                  │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┼
```

I have tried using a match and with but i am not getting it right as i am new to neo4j.

Comment: Please see: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).

Comment: Please post your query and your sample data. Thanks.